# how to recognize execution options in bash code chunk in a quarto document?

Tags: bash, rstudio, quarto

I have a quarto document with some bash shell code

````
```{bash}
#| echo: true
#| eval: false
rsync somethingreallybigfromtheinternet
```
````

I have also `r` code chunks where I can see that the same execution options get highlighted, but not for the `bash` code chunk.
Why is that? Bash does not have execution options?

An image is way better...
[image]